# Decode escaped characters in URL

Tags: python, escaping

I have a list containing URLs with escaped characters in them. Those characters have been set by `urllib2.urlopen` when it recovers the html page:

```
http://www.sample1webpage.com/index.php?title=%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5&action=edit
http://www.sample1webpage.com/index.php?title=%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5&action=history
http://www.sample1webpage.com/index.php?title=%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5&variant=zh
```

Is there a way to transform them back to their unescaped form in python?

P.S.: The URLs are encoded in utf-8

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Using `urllib` package (`import urllib`) :

## Python 2.7

From [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) :

> `urllib.unquote(string)`
>
> Replace `%xx` escapes by their single-character equivalent.
>
> Example: `unquote('/%7Econnolly/')` yields `'/~connolly/'`.

## Python 3

From [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) :

> `urllib.parse.unquote(string, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')`
>
> […]
>
> Example: `unquote('/El%20Ni%C3%B1o/')` yields `'/El Niño/'`.

Comment: the unquote shows as i said above sample.com/index.php?title=\xe9\xa6\x96\xe9\xa1\xb5&action=edi ... maybe i did not explain myself very well in this case... but the url is a chinese one and i want to decode to it's original char, not the unquote one

Comment: @dyoser You need to put this in your question.

Comment: @root45 this is a comment to one answer... so it's right good here. Thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: @dyoser My point is that you left out important information in your question. You asked an unclear question and got a downvote and two answers telling you the same thing. If you include the fact that you want to decode Chinese characters, people might be able to help you. Both of these people have correct answers. Your issue is dealing with Unicode. Your strings are UTF-16 which is not going to be handled by default. People may have known that if you included it in your question like I suggested.

Comment: No, it's UTF-8. Specifically "首页".

Comment: @root45 it's not utf-16... as ignacio said is utf-8. And again, maybe the question is unclear maybe not.

Comment: @dyoser I corrected myself in the next comment. Maybe your question is perfectly clear, but given the downvote, the two identical answers and the lack of activity for four hours, I'd say you could benefit from editing your question and adding more information. But hey, it's up to you. I'm not interested in the answer. It's your loss.

Comment: Just a note that for python3, this is `urllib.parse.unquote`

Comment: unquote decodes only %xx escape sequences. It doesn't replace the plus sign (+) with an ASCII space ' '.  For that, unquote_plus() must be used.

Comment: For python3 it is also in `urllib.request.unquote`

Comment: In Python 3, I'm using `urlparse` and then `unquote` to get unquoted versions of the username and password from a URL. But I'm surprised there isn't a one-step way to do it. Have I missed something?

Comment: @Ben This is because `urllib.request` [imports several methods](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/urllib/request.py) from `urllib.parse`.  Better import the former if you only need `unquote`, but no need to import it if you already need the latter for something else, I guess.

Answer (score 39):

And if you are using `Python3` you could use:

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.unquote(url)
```

Comment: Also in `urllib.request.unquote`

Answer (score 18):

or `urllib.unquote_plus`

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote('erythrocyte+membrane+protein+1%2C+PfEMP1+%28VAR%29')
'erythrocyte+membrane+protein+1,+PfEMP1+(VAR)'
>>> urllib.unquote_plus('erythrocyte+membrane+protein+1%2C+PfEMP1+%28VAR%29')
'erythrocyte membrane protein 1, PfEMP1 (VAR)'
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`urllib.unquote`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)

Comment: when i use the unquote (thanks by the way...) it shows this string http://sample.com/index.php?title=\xe9\xa6\x96\xe9\xa1\xb5&action=edi and i know they're chinese chars... how can i see them? I guess this is unicode, right?

Comment: That's in your question already. Those are the UTF-8 bytes; you can convert them to a Unicode string with `b"\xe9\xa6\x96\xe9\xa1\xb5".decode("utf-8")` (using somewhat more modern Python syntax now).

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

def unquote(url):
  return re.compile('%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})',re.M).sub(lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)), url)
```

Comment: Why would you manually use regex and lambdas when there's a built in library that does what you need, probably even more thoughtfully?

Comment: Cool solution! `urllib2` is not part of standard python distri.  `re` is.

Comment: parsing html with regex isn't usually the best idea.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - it only handles encoded ASCII. If the URL has any encoded non-ASCII this'll corrupt it, since *each UTF-8 byte* is encoded as a separate % escape. You instead need to do a uft8-decode on entire sequences of consecutive escapes, and replace them with the 1 or more characters that result.