# How to convert `%xx` code in URL back to the corresponding UTF-8 character

Tags: python

For example, I want to convert

`'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ana%C3%AFs_Croze'`

to

`u'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaïs_Croze'`

How to do this in Python?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136788/decode-escaped-characters-in-url

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> print urllib2.unquote('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ana%C3%AFs_Croze')
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaïs_Croze
>>>
```

The above code as a runnable 'bunk' http://codebunk.com/bunk#-Iy8_GcBQ02jlMauuYP4

Comment: Is this locale dependent ? I get `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AnaÃ¯s_Croze`

Comment: @Emmanuel : Your file (or shell) must be unicode encoded. For files use as first line something like `# encoding: utf-8` and make sure that your editor saves it as unicode.