# Jetty: How do we allow HttpServletRequest.GetParameter() to parse % symbol?

Tags: java, http, servlets, encoding, jetty

When handling urls of the syntax

> http://foo.com?bar=%test%

jetty throws an IllegalArgumentException saying its not a valid hex value.

We tried to change the character encoding to UTF-16 but that still does not parse %. Is there a way to allow '%' to be parsed by getParameter or getParameterMap function in HttpPServletRequest interface?

Expected output for the getParameter("bar") = "%test%"

Comment: "%" is a key word for URI, and the jetty will get parsing exception when you request "bar=%test%" due to http protocol. as i know, the "%" equals to "%25",so you can request "http://foo.com?bar=%25test%25" to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `%` in a URL/URI is a reserved character for processing [Percent Encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) characters in a URL/URI. - see [RFC3986 Section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)

What Jetty saw is the `%` character, and then has to use the next 2 characters `te` to decode which UTF-8 byte you are wanting, which in your test case results in an invalid percent encoding.

At its most fundamental, your example URL/URI is a "Malformed URI". (try to decode it in [Javascript](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) or [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8136831/775715) or [Perl](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq9.html#How-do-I-decode-or-create-those--encodings-on-the-web-))

Also Note, all URL/URI processing is effectively UTF-8 (it is standard and spec breaking to parse a URL/URI in a different encoding scheme)