# Percent signs in url

Tags: python, url, selenium

Is it possible to change an URL which contains percent signs like

```
 http%3A%2F%2Funiversities.ac%2Fshow_article.php%3Fid%3D61&amp
```

to normal URL readable by human like

```
http://universities.ac/show_article.php?id=61
```

using Selenium?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode escaped characters in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136788/decode-escaped-characters-in-url)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Selenium. You can use the `urlparse` module in the standard library.

```
from urlparse import unquote      # python2
from urllib.parse import unquote  # python3
unquote('http%3A%2F%2Funiversities.ac%2Fshow_article.php%3Fid%3D61&amp')
```

Comment: The ampersand `&` (HTML-entity: `&amp`) at the and of the URL does not seem to be unquoted. As a quick workaround you could pass the unquoted URL string to [`html.unencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) in oder to convert HTML-entities

Answer (score 1):

You can use urllib unquote as follows

```
url='http%3A%2F%2Funiversities.ac%2Fshow_article.php%3Fid%3D61&amp'
url=urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')
```