# Is this Unicode? String? Ascii? How to convert or delete it from a string?

Tags: python, unicode

If you open this page: `www.postkhmer.com/ព័ត៌មានជាតិ`

You will see this in their anchor tag?

`/%E1%9E%96%E1%9F%90%E1%9E%8F%E1%9F%8C%E1%9E%98%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%93%E1%9E%87%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%8F%E1%9E%B7/%E1%9E%80%E1%9E%98%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%98%E1%9E%80%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%9F%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%93%E1%9E%BE%E1%9E%8F%E1%9E%BB%E1%9E%9B%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%80%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%85%E1%9F%81%E1%9E%89%E1%9E%8A%E1%9E%B8%E1%9E%80%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%B9%E1%9E%94%E1%9E%A2%E1%9E%BC%E1%9E%9F%E1%9E%91%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%96%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%99%E1%9E%9A%E1%9F%84%E1%9E%84%E1%9E%85%E1%9E%80%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%9A`

[image]

What is the type of this thing? When I copy it and paste in browser, after it's domain name:

`www.postkhmer.com/%E1%9E%96%E1%9F%90%E1%9E%8F%E1%9F%8C%E1%9E%98%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%93%E1%9E%87%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%8F%E1%9E%B7/%E1%9E%80%E1%9E%98%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%98%E1%9E%80%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%9F%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%93%E1%9E%BE%E1%9E%8F%E1%9E%BB%E1%9E%9B%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%80%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%85%E1%9F%81%E1%9E%89%E1%9E%8A%E1%9E%B8%E1%9E%80%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%B9%E1%9E%94%E1%9E%A2%E1%9E%BC%E1%9E%9F%E1%9E%91%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%96%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%99%E1%9E%9A%E1%9F%84%E1%9E%84%E1%9E%85%E1%9E%80%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%9A`

It converts into this:`www.postkhmer.com//ព័ត៌មានជាតិ/កម្មករស្នើតុលាការចេញដីការឹបអូសទ្រព្យរោងចក្រ`

How can I convert it into Khmer Language in Python? or How can I delete from a big string?

Comment: It might be called [percent encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2742985/5067311)

Comment: It is [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Use [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) to decode, for example.

Comment: ok thank you, how can i deal with it in python? like delete it or convert into a readable unicode?

Comment: ok thank you it works great by using urllib.unquote

Comment: Since you don't have any answers and the question is solved, I suggest that you consider deleting your question, as it is unlikely to help future readers:)

Comment: For reference, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136788/decode-escaped-characters-in-url. I think that answers this question so will mark this one a duplicate.

Comment: yes, i agree it's duplicate. should I delete this question?

Comment: Yes, I think you should.

Comment: nah, just one question, the world is not gonna end. so many other things are worst than this question, so just leave it here.

Comment: Just keep it as it has a context related to Khmer unicode that in some cases, developer who works on related topic, may find it by language context.