# Python trouble with dashes in web scraping

Tags: python

I have a simple script that scrapes Google for a link and then scrapes that link. However, some links contain dashes in them, and for some reason it comes out like this `%25E2%2580%2593` in my script (in the url). So it would now look like this: `http://myaddress.com/search?q=The_%25E2%2580%2593_World` when I want it to look like this `http://myaddress.com/search?q=The_–_World`. How can I go about doing this? Should I be using UTF-8 encoding/decoding?

**Edit:**
I tried double unquoting (with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136788/decode-escaped-characters-in-url) link) but to no avail. Instead I get a result that looks like this: `http://myaddress.com/search?q=The_â€“_World`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode escaped characters in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136788/decode-escaped-characters-in-url)

Comment: That post did not help; my dash was still 'escaped'.

Answer (score 3):

The URL appears to be **double** URL encoded.

To decode to its raw form use the urllib libraries' `parse.unquote` function to perform double URL decoding:

```
import urllib.parse

url = 'http://myaddress.com/search?q=The_%25E2%2580%2593_World'
urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.unquote(url))
```

which decodes to the desired 'http://myaddress.com/search?q=The_–_World' URL.

**EDIT**:

As you have explained that you are using *Python 2.7*, the equivalent decode function would be `unquote(url)` (refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)).

```
import urllib

url = 'http://myaddress.com/search?q=The_%25E2%2580%2593_World'
print(urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(url))).decode('utf-8')
```

Output:

`http://myaddress.com/search?q=The_–_World`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Python 2.7; and I know that `urllib.parse` is a python 3 library. I tried using `urllib.url2pathname` instead, and this did show promising signs at first but instead gave me this `P:\\myaddress.com\search?q=The_â€“_World` (when I double decode it). I assume this has something to do with not decoding in UTF-8?