# IndexError: tuple index out of range postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, pgcrypto

I have been using the pgcrypto extension module's digest function to encode several values.  I recently discovered that some of the URL values that I'm trying to encode contain `'%,'` which throw an

> *IndexError: tuple index out of range.*

I have spent hours today trying to fix this issue, but so far I have not corrected this error in my code.  How do I encode a `URL` that contains special characters?

This works in `pgAdmin4`, but not in my python script:

```
encode(digest('domainname.com/pub-cgi/retrieve.pl?doc=file%2F1999&zone_19=300%2A%20','sha256')
```

How do I encode a URL that contains special characters?

Comment: Please post your code exactly how it is in your program. The snippet you have provided contains a syntax error (extra closing quote) and won't run. You will also get better answers if you post a complete traceback.

Comment: That extra closing quote was added by mistake when I sanitized the snippet for posting.

Comment: The only URLs that throw this error contain a %.  If I remove this encoding piece from my code everything loads correctly including the other elements, which I encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research on Stack Overflow, I found a solution that was posted years ago.

[Decode escaped characters in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136788/decode-escaped-characters-in-url)

This is the code that I used to solve my encoding problem:

```
# This section of code reformats a href with URL encoding
def unquote(url):
   return re.compile('%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})',re.M).sub(lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)), url)

# URL with encoding - https://www.somedomainname.com/pubs/retrieve.pl?doc=some%2Ddocument%2Dname.pdf

print (unquote('https://www.somedomainname.com/pubs/retrieve.pl?doc=some%2Ddocument%2Dname.pdf'))

# Output - https://www.somedomainname.com/pubs/retrieve.pl?doc=some-document-name.pdf
```

Now that I have this URL reformatted, I can use the pgcrypto extension module's digest function to encode with a SHA-256 hash.

```
encode(digest('https://www.somedomainname.com/pubs/retrieve.pl?doc=some-document-name.pdf','sha256')
```

**SPECIAL NOTE:** I remove the href protocol from the URLs prior to hashing them, because it prevents duplicates, which is a concern of mine.